# How to connect to a second monitor without restarting X?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xrandr, bspwm, xrdb

Every time I have to connect to an external monitor, it remains "disconnected" according to `xrandr` and the second screen remains black.

To solve this problem, I always have to close all my GUI apps and the X server, login again and restart everything.

Tests I did : if I go to `tty2` before doing this, the screen is duplicated as expected but when I go back to `tty1` (which I use to `startx`) it disappears.

My config is Arch Linux + bspwm, my `.xinitrc` is simply `exec bspwm`

I'd really like to keep my programs open whenever I need to do a presentation.

Comment: Have you tried using `xrandr` to set up your screens?

Comment: Yes, it's what I do once I have restarted X in order to change the disposition of the second screen(```xrandr --output DP1 --above eDP1```), but before that I just can't detect the existence of a second screen

Comment: `xrandr` doesn't detect them either?

Comment: No, that's my problem.

Comment: Doesn't your display/window manager have it's own native (GUI) app to change that? If not: I worked around this stuff in other combinations by installing monitor managers from other dm's/wm's. Like xfce4-display-settings, gnome-control-center display, etc. Ugly, likely to fsck things up but under water they all do the xrandr stuff...

Comment: Well I'd really like a command-line option because I want to script it, and I want to understand what I do wrong with xrandr (which usage seems quite simple).
(No there's no gui app in my wm)